# How Can I connect the SendGrid dynamic templates to azure custom policy to send custom verification e-mail?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-api-v2

I searched so many times about this this problem, but I couldn't find anything. Please help me if you know.
I have a B2C on azure portal. In here, there is a policy. If I use this policy to verify the e-mail, it works without problem. But I want to use 2 different policy to send different verification e-mail. So I added new custom policy. But when I click to "run now" sigin_and_signup policy it verified with other verification e-mail. By the way I created APIKey and tenantID(d-abcsdsvxxxxxxx) on the sendGrid portal.

Comment: Hi, I've added an initial answer based on what you've described here, but if you can add some examples from the current policies you have that would help track down the specific problem.

Comment: I can explain step by step. 
1. I created custom policy 5 xml page(signin_signup, password_reset,profiledit,TrustFrameworkbase,TrustFrameworkextension).xml
2. edited the tenantID(d-xxxxxx...) in TrustFrameworkbase , edited proxyIdentityExpreinceFrameworkapplcationID and IdentityExpreinceFrameworkapplcationID
I click to run now on custom policy(signin_signup).
I enter my e-mail address to sign up, it verified with my azure active director(default template).

Comment: Hi, @yalçın Please let us know if you are still looking for any Help?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid) should be able to help you out with how SendGrid can be integrated with B2C to send custom verification emails. If you want to send a completely customised verification email (instead of the AAD default email) then you need to follow that documentation step-by-step.

If you've already implemented custom email verification templates and your two policies are both using the same template instead of different ones then the part you're probably having problems with is the [claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid#add-the-claims-transformation). If you take a look at that section of the docs you'll see that there's a `template_id`, that's the id of the specific SendGrid email template that B2C will use.

If you want there to be two different custom email templates used then you'll need two different claims transformations, each with the `template_id` of the email it should be using. You'd also need two `SendOtp` technical profiles, each using a different claims transformation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added template_id to claims transformation. But I have one claims transformation. If I try verify the e-mail, it sends default template. But I want to my template that created. @Dave D

Comment: @yalçın Ah, if it's using the default template and you want it to use your custom one then you need to follow the first docs link in my answer and do what it describes step-by-step. I've updated my answer to be a bit clearer there.

Comment: I had this doc. I did all things step by step. but it did not work.I have template_id, and entered field. but no action.

Comment: You're going to need to post the relevant sections from your policies I'm afraid. If you've already been through those docs then there may be something subtle that's not configured correctly.

Comment: Yes, I think, you are right. but really is it possible that I can use the my custom policy and add the my custom email verification?
By the way I set everthing, but it did not work.

Comment: Dave, I can post my policy to you. Can you help me with this problem? I am sure that it is a bit problem but I can not see it.